# sencha app build terminates after Attempting Cordova Build for platforms "ios"

Tags: cordova, extjs

We are building an application on platform "ios" with sencha. After executing command : sencha app build native on terminal, it terminates after attempting of cordova build for ios. So, anybody with solution is appreciable.

> command used: **sencha app build native**

We are using versions -
sencha   : 6.2.1.29
cordova  : 6.5.0
phonegap : 8.2.2

Following code is displayed on terminal, but didn't build 
  successful:

> **[INF] [Cordova] Attempting Cordova Build for platforms "ios"** 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript] Building for iPhone XS Max Simulator 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript] Building project: /Users/test/Desktop/UNHR_New 2/UNHR2/UNHR/UN Human
>   Rights/UNHR/cordova/platforms/ios/HumanRights.xcworkspace 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]   Configuration: Debug 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]   Platform: emulator 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript] Build settings from command line: 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]     CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/test/Desktop/UNHR_New 2/UNHR2/UNHR/UN Human
>   Rights/UNHR/cordova/platforms/ios/build/emulator 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]     SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.0 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]     SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/test/Desktop/UNHR_New 2/UNHR2/UNHR/UN Human
>   Rights/UNHR/cordova/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript] 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript] Build settings from configuration file '''/Users/test/Desktop/UNHR_New 2/UNHR2/UNHR/UN Human
>   Rights/UNHR/cordova/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig''':
>   
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]     CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]     CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
>   
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]     CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]     ENABLE_BITCODE = NO 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]     GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]     HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include"
>   "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include"
>   "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"
>   "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]     OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC 
>   **[INF]** [shellscript]     SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h